# Oracle Apex 5.1 Interactive Grid Filter

Tags: oracle-apex

Interactive Grid 5.1: I would like to suppress the initial search, that means "no search without a filter". How?

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, I created an interactive grid (IG) based on Scott's EMP table. By default, once the page is ran, it retrieves all employees because there's no `WHERE` condition in IG's query.

Then I switched DEBUG mode on, entered "king" into the search field and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Of course, King's data showed on the screen, but that's not the interesting part - debug info is.

If you look at it, you'll see that Apex rewrote your "original" query and added some extra info. This is what you're looking for:

```
Rewrite SQL to: select a.* from (select q.*,count(*) over () "APEX$TOTAL_ROW_COUNT"
from(select q.*
from(select "ROWID" "APEX$ROWID","EMPNO","ENAME","JOB","MGR","HIREDATE","SAL","COMM","DEPTNO"
from(select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       MGR,
       HIREDATE,
       SAL,
       COMM,
       DEPTNO
  from EMP
)q
)q
where (1=2 or upper(q."ENAME") like :apex$1 or upper(q."JOB") like :apex$2)
)q
)a
where ROWNUM <= :p$_max_rows
```

Pay attention to the `WHERE` clause which says:

```
where (1=2 or upper(q."ENAME") like :apex$1 or upper(q."JOB") like :apex$2)
```

Aha! As ENAME and JOB are the only VARCHAR2 columns, it seems that Apex expects any of those values to filter data. OK then, I rewrote my own IG's `SELECT` statement to

```
select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       MGR,
       HIREDATE,
       SAL,
       COMM,
       DEPTNO
  from EMP
where :apex$1 is not null and :apex$2 is not null  --> added this
```

and ran the page again. Guess what? IG's grid is empty!

So, if that's what you are looking for, give it a try - run the page in Debug mode, review is results and modify your query according to what you see.

Comment: Good idea. Your solution works until the user adds or removes a column from the report through the action menu. If there is one column less in your example, the report ist always empty because :apex$2 is null.

Comment: Oh well; I'm far from being perfect. I just shared what I've found out; do some research yourself, you'll - hopefully - improve what I managed to do. What is the purpose of doing the whole job, anyway?

Comment: I have spend hours on a solution for this problem and I tried to use your solution, but without any luck so far. Thank you. I tried the new javascript config-options for ig, but it seems that the option "isRequired" does not work.

Comment: Sorry to hear that; it seems that you'll have to live with it. Maybe one of future releases will improve IG options and you'll be able to easily achieve what you want.